# Problemas com Oauth google

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, google, oauth

Não consigo inserir uma URI válida nas credenciais da api de autenticação do google, sempre tenho como retorno o seguinte erro:

> redirect_uri_mismatch.

Já tentei todas as recomendações `http: //localhost /`, `http: //localhost :3000/`, `http: //localhost /callback`, `http: //localhost:58889 /`. Enfim, não sei mais o que fazer. Estou trabalhando com uma aplicação hibrida usando `Cordova` e `Ionic`, estou usando o Intel XDK como plataforma.

Comment: Voce ja listou a URL no console da API?

Comment: Já sim. A inseri e o mesmo erro aconteceu.

Comment: Tem que colocar a mesma url tanto no console quanto na programaçaão

Answer (score -2):

Coloca `http://localhost` (sem a barra invertida no final) no console da API